# React App using Tailwindcss - Image Responsiveness as Screen Grows the Image Stretches Even though have CSS not to

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I tried and looked up all that I could and still not finding any solutions or clues. Someone out there knows and. I appreciate the understanding, thank you.

Code for div's that house the backgroundImage for the slider - I have tired `object-fits`, `covers...`, even in a css file but cannot get the responsiveness to work on the `md`, `lg` screens for Tailwindcss or css on the image's `height` as the screen gets bigger.

Video shows the response issue as the screen grows and shrinks. Mobile view is what it should be and works as Tailwindcss is mobile first, but cannot control for the larger screens at the moment. Need help on that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../components/HomeSlider.css';
import { images } from '../helpers/HomeSliderData';

let count = 0;

function HomeSlider() {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    startSlider();
  }, []);

  const startSlider = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      handleNextImage();
    }, 4000);
  };

  const handleNextImage = () => {
    count = (count + 1) % images.length;
    setCurrentImage(count);
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen-xl h-[420px] ml-auto mr-auto relative">
      <div
        className="w-full h-full flex  bg-center duration-800 absolute"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${images[currentImage].backgroundImage})`,
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeSlider;
```

Video Demo: https://youtu.be/TZcbqXPAFbc

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to rework your `h-[420px]` class. This is a static height, but the width of the element will scale – thus the difference in image proportion when the width is a lot wider. You could consider applying an aspect-ratio value via an [`aspect-*` class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio#using-custom-values) instead of defining a static height.

Comment: Sweet,  I will check those out, Thank you for the info. BRB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the height of the image at `420px`, you can look into serving responsive images. You would basically have different images for different screen sizes.

For background image you have the [image-set](https://caniuse.com/css-image-set) but the support is not the best. If you can change to an img tag, then the support is better for [srcset](https://caniuse.com/?search=srcset).

Check out the below code snippet result by resizing your window.

```html
<img 
  alt="sample image" 
  src="http://via.placeholder.com/1080x420"
  srcset="
    http://via.placeholder.com/640x420 640w, 
    http://via.placeholder.com/1080x420 1080w,
  "
  />
```